# Avoid setter method generation via jsonschema2pojo

Tags: java, json, getter-setter, jsonschema, jsonschema2pojo

I want to generate a class via json that does not have setter method for a given property. Is there any option in jsonschema2pojo json schema definition that can help me achieve this?

Comment: have you tried this >> https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as of now, jsonschema2pojo doesn't provide a way to nail it down to specific property. You can do it for entire file. If you are using the tool online you can un-check 'Include getters and setters' and if you are using it in code, you need to extend and override methods in DefaultGenerationConfig